# Reliable and performant cheap (ish) hosting for ASP.NET 3.5 and mysql

Tags: hosting, asp.net-2.0, web-hosting, shared-hosting

I'm looking for someone reasonably cheap but better than the majority of budget hosts out there. I'm currently with brinkster.net and I've become increasingly annoyed at the their immense unreliability and low available resources.

Fasthosts business plan is close, but has no mysql, only has ASP.NET 2.0 and is maybe slightly more expensive than I was hoping for.

Answer (score 2):

I have had several sites hosted on http://discountasp.net and have had very good results.  They are on year 4 of being voted best ASP.NET host in the asp.netPRO reader's choice survey.

Comment: I always suspect those reader's choice surveys / hosting rating sites are created by the hosts themselves, but nonetheless, glad to hear a positive review.

Answer (score 1):

I have had great luck with [Viux.com](http://hsp.viux.com/redirector.cgi/ID,4f9bb71080) - their customer service is top-notch and they were quick to implement asp.net 3.5. I moved all my sites (5) to Viux now and couldn't be happier. Very reliable and I can't say enough about their super fast and friendly service! MySQL comes free with all of their plans and MSSQL is $2/month.

I have tried quite a few hosts, and these guys are my favorite. If you decide on another, just make sure it is not M6.net, their customer service was just horrendous!

Comment: Can anyone expand on the comment regarding M6?  I was just looking at their site and the hosting options seem great.  What was the bad customer service experience?

Comment: you can read all about my experience here: http://naspinski.net/post/M6net-is-the-worst-host-of-all-time.aspx

Comment: Not sure about Viux, but I have had nothing but problems with M6. Trying to host an ASP.NET MVC site, which is constantly going down due to them making incorrect server configuration changes.

Comment: I feel for anyone who has to deal with M6 - get out of there as fast as you can!

Answer (score 1):

[GoDaddy](http://godaddy.com/) supports .NET 3.5 and mysql on their basic hosting packages.

Answer (score 1):

We've used GoDaddy at my primary employment (day job :-) for several years and have had a positive experience with them (I also recently switched my home business from Yahoo! Small Business to GoDaddy).

Regarding reliability, I haven't had any problems with downtime. As a result, I have no first hand tech support experience with GoDaddy, but from what I read on the boards their tech support is pretty good (comparable to any other tech support I guess). They offer LINUX and Windows hosting (if that matters to you), MySQL and MSSQL database support, and .NET 3.5/AJAX.

And the price was reasonable, as far as I'm concerned.

Answer (score 0):

I've been with these guys for quite a bit,
http://www.webhost4life.com/

Cheap and cheerful.

Answer (score 0):

Something that might interest you -- ScottGu's latest blog post mentions Amazon's EC2 is going to support ASP.NET.

http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2008/10/coming-soon-ama.html

Depending on what you plan on doing, that could be of interest. It's usually pretty cheap, as well.

Answer (score 0):

Dreamhost supports stackoverflow's podcast

http://www.dreamhost.com/

Edit: It looks like they don't support ASP.NET though, that was unexpected.

Comment: Indeed - Dreamhost is a big PHP advocate and runs Linux on its servers pretty much exclusively afaik.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ReliableSite.Net](http://payments.reliablesite.net/aff.php?aff=026)

It is cheap and good. They even throw a free MS SQL 2005 database(1 GB- Extra DB costs $1) what other places charge $10/Month and give you less then 500MB of space.

So you can upgrade to mssql 2005(not sure if you where just using mysql because it is cheaper).

If you don't want to bother changing to mssql 2005 then you can save it for another project(you can host unlimited domains on Reliable) and use the mysql database that they also throw in for free.

I find Reliable does not nickle and dim you for every single thing and gives reasonable prices and have great coupons.

Like this coupon for 15% off for life: "aspforum"

Answer (score 0):

Planet Small Business http://www.planetsmb.com/ are pretty cheap, and have excellent customer service.

The only hassle I've had with them is over hosting WCF services. I wasn't able to host it as a native ASP.Net service, you have to do a bit of extra plumbing to manually add a service host, but nothing impossible, and their customer support was there ready and waiting.

Highly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I Use SmarterAsp.net to host Multiple Sites  ; they have good control panel and their Price start fro $2.95/Month you can also get 60 days free trial so you can decide if it's suitable for you
http://www.SmarterASP.NET/index?r=100819197